# Jquery weird behavior - object.click

Tags: jquery, click, onload

Please take a look on this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Main - Annex7</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(load);

        function load() {
            var objectX= $("#objectX")
            objectX.click(alert('auch'));
        }
    </script>
```

Should not the 'click' event get fired when I do click on objectX???
But this alert is fired when I load the document...

I´m a little confused, please any help would be very well received.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the click event to:

```
objectX.click(function(){
    alert('auch');
});
```

you need to pass a function into the event,
 if you just pass an action you will get errors

Comment: @Lug ive noticed that you dont accept ansers (only 60%) people would be more likely to help on future Q's if you accepted answers that you deemed correct ^_^

Comment: Now...? hehehe. sorry. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in a function, such as an anonymous one...

```
objectX.click(function() { alert('auch'); });
```